# Hibernate, Spring and MySQL : unable to set the charset to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, xml, spring, hibernate, utf-8

I have an issue with Hibernate and Spring : I am unable to use the UTF-8 charset everywhere, and I have some issues with accented letters (like *éèà*...). Here is a part of my database creation :

```
-- Dropping and creating database again
DROP DATABASE `miniprojetjee`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `miniprojetjee` default character set = "UTF8" default collate = "utf8_general_ci";

-- My user
GRANT ALL ON `miniprojetjee`.* to 'miniprojetjee'@'localhost' identified by 'miniprojetjee';

CREATE TABLE Utilisateur (
    username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
    telephone VARCHAR(20),
    mail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description MEDIUMBLOB,
    date_inscription TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- .../...
```

I think this implies that my database is in full UTF-8. So after this, I configured spring and hibernate through my `web.xml`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- .../... -->
```

And my `dispatcher.xml` :

```
<!-- .../... -->
<bean id="dataSourceMySql" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojetjee?useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8"/>
    <property name="username" value="miniprojetjee"/>
    <property name="password" value="miniprojetjee"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMySql"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="dao"/>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <!-- Tryied a lot of things...
            <prop key="connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- .../... -->
```

Is there any way to solve this ? I am unable to find anything that work right now.

Comment: You may need `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your DB URL parameter `characterEncoding=utf-8` so the connection URL should be

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojetjee?useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"/>
```